# Can't figure out what this symbol in a Kac-Rice method means

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, notation, gaussian

I've been reading a paper and I can't seem to understand what this cursive symbol "N" means at the beginning of the equation below. It's in the context of a staircase function and the Kac-Rice method. It's meant to be a function for the solutions between eigenvalues (if that helps). I've tried reaching out to the author but they haven't replied back yet. Is there a name for this symbol?
[image: Equation with unknown symbol]
[Source of equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nGf3s.png)

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.12452.pdf , I believe they may be implying it is the normalization function